# How do I update Wikipedia citations for pages which are no longer available?

Tags: wikipedia

The Wikipedia page for [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) includes the following citation.

> Bott, Ed (2007-02-02). ["What triggers User Account Control prompts?"](http://www.edbott.com/weblog/?p=1602).

---

Currently this citation leads to a [404 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), meaning the article is no longer available.

[image: 404 error]

It appears the page was removed fairly recently, as I was able to find [an archived version on Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160705222224/http://www.edbott.com/weblog/2007/02/what-triggers-user-account-control-prompts/) from July 2016. I want to update the citation to use the archived version, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

**How do I update Wikipedia citations for pages that are no longer available?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many citations use the [Cite web template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Cite_web), or any of the other [Citation Style 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Citation_Style_1) templates. All of these have an `archive-url`, `archive-date` and `url-status` parameter. Simply add these to the citation.

- `archive-url` is of course the url to the Wayback Machine (or another archival website)
- `archive-date` should be set to the date the webpage was archived, preferably in the same date formatting as the existing `date` parameter.
- `url-status` should be set to either `dead`, `live`, `unfit`, or `usurped`. If the original URL is still available, set it to `live`, otherwise, set it to `dead`. This will change which of the links (`archive-url` or `url`) is linked to first in the rendered citation. If the original link is no longer suitable at all (perhaps because the someone else owns that domain now) set it to `unfit` or `usurped`, which will prevent the original link from rendering at all.

For the Citation you mentioned, you can see [in this diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_Account_Control&type=revision&diff=848795101&oldid=840729105) how I've done this. Note: `url-status` used to be `dead-url`, which has been deprecated. My edit from July 2018 has been updated in September 2019, see [this diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_Account_Control&type=revision&diff=916379420&oldid=905561279).